# How to append button and onclick event with the ngx-lightbox?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular6

I installed [ngx-lightbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lightbox) and it works perfect. My need is to extend this lightbox to add a simple button to the bottom which will fire an event on onclick.

```
export class lightBox extends LightboxConfig {
 func() {
 }
}
```

I am trying to extend this `Ngx-lightbox`, how can I extend it?

Demo--> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8a4qam)

Comment: please share your code in detail?

Comment: i did not wrote any code i just installed ngx-lightbox

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8a4qam)  this is my stackblitz for demo

Comment: do you want to add a button to the bottom of popup image?

Comment: yes in the backdrop

Comment: you can use bootstrap modals to do something similar to ngx-lightbox ... there you'd have all the control in your hands

Comment: I want to place a button by extending the plugin(ngx-lightbox) not in bootstrap modals.